# LogBack as SharedLibrary in IBM WebSphere 8.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, logback

I want to use LogBack with IBM WebSphere 8.5 as a Shared Library. My problem is I don't know where to put the logback.xml so I can redirects some of my logs to different files. Currently all my logs are directed to System.out.log in WAS, which I don't want.

I've tried to put the logback.xml in my Dynamic Application Project WEB-INF/classes folder, in my EJB Project ejbModule folder, with no success.

I've tried googling all over, but I cannot find anything pointing to this issue.

Any idea?

Regards,

Comment: If you use logback and have the logback.xml packed in your EAR, I think you logs are no longer visible in the WebSphere log files, is this correct?
Doing so wouldn't you also lose the ability to change log level using the WAS console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've successfully used SLF4J API with Logback implementation with WAS 7. My configuration was:

- logback-classic-x.jar, logback-core-x.jar (, slf4j-api-x.jar) in my EAR's lib directory
- logback.xml in my EJB's root source folder (ejbModule)

And that was it.

Placing logback.xml in a JAR and placing that JAR into your EAR's lib should also work.

Don't you get any logback related errors during application startup?

Comment: I've done as you recommends above, and logback works with all EJBs in my EJB module. But calls to my JSF backing beans in the EJB module from the Dynamic Web Project does not log as intended, i.e. it still logs to System.out.

I put the logback-classic, logback-core, and slf4j-api in my EAR's lib directory together with a JAR file containing the logback.xml.

Comment: It might be a bit unrelated, but are you sure you have JSF backing beans in your EJB module?

Comment: they are not really JSF annotated backing beans, they are CDI annotated backing beans, accessed by JSF Facelets in my Dynamic Web Project

Comment: finally I can set up logback with WAS 8.5. I think I followed your above steps wrongly in the first place. Anyways you steps really do the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From [Logback FAQ](http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#configFileLocation):

put logback.xml in

- any folder declared in classpath
- WEB-INF/classes directly

Comment: Yes I've read that, too. But when I had only an EJB module in my EAR, the only way it worked for me was to place logback.xml in my EJB module's root source folder, ejbModule. I've tried moving to several other places within my EJB module without success.

Comment: @Csaba: yes, I think that's the correct place to put the logback.xml for the EJBs, but not for the backing beans, tho. :(